# How can I dynamically update the span and the contents of the first row of headers in a table with 2 rows of headers in ASP.Net Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a table with 2 rows of headers, both of them update dynamically from 2 separate database tables. The content update part is ok, it works. The problem is, the cells in the first row must span over whatever the number of entries of that particular category is in the 2nd row.
I've grouped the second row categories by elements with their id, counted the ids and put them in a ViewBag.

The first row model:

```
    [Table("categories")]
    public class CategoriesModel
    {
        [Column("category_id")]
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Column("category_name")]
        //[Required]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

Second row model:

```
[Table("materials")]
    public class MaterialModel
    {
        [Column("material_id")]
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Required]
        public int MaterialId { get; set; }

        [Column("height_x_width")]
        [Required]
        public string Dimensions { get; set; }

        [Column("category_id")]
        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public List<CategoriesModel> MaterialCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class NationalCampaignViewModel
    {
        public string Campaign { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<RestaurantModel> Restaurant { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<CategoriesModel> Categories { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<MaterialModel> Materials { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<OptionModel> Options { get; set; }
    }
```

the ViewModelController:

```
public class NationalCampaignViewModelController : Controller
    {
        private readonly McDdbContext _context;

        public NationalCampaignViewModelController(McDdbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: NationalCampaign
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
        {
            var campaign = await _context.NationalCampaigns.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            var restaurant = await _context.Restaurants.ToListAsync();
            //var stl = await _context.STL.ToListAsync();
            //var dtl = await _context.DTL.ToListAsync();
            var categories = await _context.CategoriesModel.ToListAsync();
            var options = await _context.OptionModel.ToListAsync();
            var materials = await _context.MaterialModel.ToListAsync();
            var colSpan = materials.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryId).GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
            ViewBag.ColSpan = colSpan.Values;

            var tables = new NationalCampaignViewModel
            {
                Campaign = campaign.CampaignName,
                Restaurant = from r in restaurant select r,
                Categories = from c in categories orderby c.CategoryId select c,
                //Options = from o in options select o,
                Materials = from m in materials orderby m.CategoryId select m
            };

            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            return View(tables);
        }
```

The View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



<h1>@Model.Campaign</h1>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table-bordered">

                @foreach (var span in ViewBag.ColSpan)
                {
                    <colgroup>
                        <col span="@span" />
                    </colgroup>
                }
                <thead>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Restaurant.FirstOrDefault().Restaurant_Name)</th>

                        @foreach (var c in Model.Categories)
                        {
                            <th scope="colgroup">@c.CategoryName</th>
                        }
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Dimensions</th>
                        @foreach (var m in Model.Materials)
                        {
                            
                            <th>@m.Dimensions</th>
                        }
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @*@foreach (var item in Model.Restaurant)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-controller="Restaurant" asp-action="Edit"
                           asp-route-id="@item.Restaurant_Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Restaurant_Name)</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }*@
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

The table with the number of columns to span over:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with dictionary.

Controller:

```
var colSpan = materials.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryId).GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
            Dictionary<string, int> headerValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            List<string> keys = new List<string>();

            foreach (var category in categories)
            {
                keys.Add(category.CategoryName);
            }


            headerValues = keys.Zip(colSpan.Values, (k, v) => new { k, v })
              .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);

            ViewBag.ColSpan = headerValues;
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Colspan)
                        {
                            <th colspan="@item.Value">@item.Key</th>
                        }
```